# Mouseleave triggering when leaving grandparent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm having a bit of trouble with a dropdown menu that triggers `fadeOut` as soon as the mouse leaves the grandparent div, I've searched this problem to death and have yet to find an elegant solution. Here is my code : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mftWK/76/)

```
var main = function() {  
    $('nav').mouseenter(function() {
        $('ul li ul').fadeIn('400');
    });

    $('nav ul li').mouseleave(function(){
        $('ul li ul').fadeOut('400');
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Explain problem Clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mftWK/79/)

```
$(this).find('ul').fadeOut('400');
```

is correct as `$('ul>li>ul').fadeOut('400');` Could not target specific (`current`) li.

Use following hierarchical flow of TAGS

```
var main = function() {
        $('nav').mouseenter(function() {
            $('ul li ul').fadeIn('400');
        });

        $('nav ul li').mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).find('ul').fadeOut('400');
        });
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured out my original problem (in addition to this one) was that `position: absolute` for the `.container` CSS property was causing it to abort: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mftWK/82/). Why would absolute positioning from a div much lower in the flow cause this?

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO: [MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mftWK/81/)**

You need to specify what element(s) you are trying to attach the event to. By adding '>' youre forcing to only attach the event to that element's children. Try this:

```
    var main = function() {
        $('nav').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).find('ul').fadeIn('400');
        });

        $('nav>ul>li').mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).find('ul').fadeOut('400');
        });
    };
```

Comment: You should include an explanation of why this may work, just providing code does not teach users what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans good call. You got me before i finished my edits. Thanks